# Absolute position and overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow, absolute

I have a modal with a list of dropdowns. When the dropdown is active - it's clipped with parent scrollable container. I would like to make every active dropdown visible above the overflow.

Already tried wrap with relative position above the scrollable container.
Would appreciate any css/js solution.

[image: Screen]

Here is the simplified example:

```js
$(document).click(function() {
    $('.list').hide();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown').click(function(event) {
      $(this).children('.list').toggle("slide");
    event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

```css
.modal {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px;
}

.scrollable-content {
  height: 120px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.scrollable-content .row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px 10px;
}


.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 4px 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown .list {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="header">
    Title
  </div>

  <div class="scrollable-content">
    <div class="row">
      <span>Row 1</span>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <span>Select</span>
        <div class="list">
          <div>Test test</div>
          <div>Test test</div>
          <div>Test test</div>
          <div>Test test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <span>Row 2</span>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <span>Select</span>
        <div class="list">
          <div>Test test</div>
          <div>Test test</div>
          <div>Test test</div>
          <div>Test test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <span>Row 3</span>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <span>Select</span>
        <div class="list">
          <div>Test test</div>
          <div>Test test</div>
          <div>Test test</div>
          <div>Test test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <span>Row 4</span>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <span>Select</span>
        <div class="list">
          <div>Test test</div>
          <div>Test test</div>
          <div>Test test</div>
          <div>Test test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <button>Cancel</button>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update your question and provide a MRE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
with relevant code parts. 

Also, please narrow down your question to a specific well-defined questionj. Thank you.

Comment: @LaurentC thanks, updated

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `overflow-y: auto`.

```css
.scrollable-content {
  height: 120px;
  /* overflow-y: auto; */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately content should be scrollable, because if we add more rows - they are not visible.